# How do you apply Tailwind CSS to all Blade Views in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

**I am new to Laravel.** Please clearly explain what changes may need to be made since I do not understand any shorthand phrases or have any 'common knowledge' when it comes to this framework. Many thanks.

**Issue:** `<h1> class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>"`doesn't work when added to blank blade.php file.

**Steps:**
0. Followed [official installation instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel).

1. Configured template path in tailwind.config.js:
   `"./resources/**/*.blade.php", "./resources/**/*.js", "./resources/**/*.vue",`
2. Added Tailwind directives to app.css:
   `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`
3. Verified `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` exists in app.blade.php

✅ **Main Question:**
How do you apply Tailwind CSS to all Blade Views in Laravel 9?

☑️ **Concern 1:**
Do I have to manually apply `@vite('resources/css/app.css')` into the head of every page in the future?

☑️ **Concern 2:**
Shouldn't it automatically apply to all blade.php files since steps 1 & 3 were completed correctly?

**Update:** All instructions from the official documentation were completed. It runs fine, but the tailwind styles still don't work without adding @vite('resources/css/app.css') directly to index.blade.php.

*Thank you for helping me learn.*

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: Yes. All instructions from the official documentation were completed. It runs fine, but the tailwind styles still don't work without adding @vite('resources/css/app.css') directly to index.blade.php.

Comment: What is the content of the css file in the `public` folder?

Comment: There is no css files present in public. I just installed Laravel 9 project, installed tailwind, npm run dev, changed route to index, and tried the H1 tag.

Answer (score -1):

```
you should make folder layouts and into folder make main.blade.php
-------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body >
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
------------------------------
and in other page for example index.blade.php

@extends('layouts.main')
@section('title', 'Index')
@section('content')

@endsection
```